# How to display content based on the URL

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I'm learning PHP and MySQL and I have a question. I've seen that a lot of sites use this, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?product_id=8
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cattegory=headphones
```

If you change the values in the URL, the content the page displays changes, so I would like to know how to use that in my webpage, thanks!

Comment: *"I'm learning PHP and MySQL and I have a question."* - Reword that to *I'm learning PHP and I have a question.* There's no SQL in your question.

Comment: But it's related, I know for example how to make a form to upload products for a webpage with PHP and PDO, but I don't know how to display just one category for example and not all of them, without creating a lot of pages..

Comment: If it's related, then show related code. Guesswork is great for charades, not coding ;-)

Comment: It's not relevant for the question, I don't have any problem in particular, I just want to know at least the name of the concept I'm asking for, if you know it just answer it, thanks :)

Comment: You've an *answer* below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the GET parameter included in the url...

```
if($_GET['product_id' == 8]) { ... }
```

Comment: Just by doing that it will return true if the URL is for example: http://www.example.com/index.php?product_id=8&other_thing=example ?

Comment: Of course, you can add more sophisticated conditions to the if. Alternatively, you can decide in the if body how the additional parameter is interpreted. In a similar fashion, you could use the `$_GET['category_id']` to build custom SQL statements to select the page contents.... Overall, I think you should first think about your *URL design* before starting to hack down the PHP part.

Comment: Supose I have some PHP code that takes the product category from the DB, and I get three categories (in an array). And display them in three `<li>` with an anchor tag and it looks like this `<li><a href="?category=<?php echo $category['1']?>"><?php echo $category['1'] ?></a></li>`. This will work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What I meant is that you could build an SQL query like `"SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_category="+$_GET["category_id"]` to find all items that should be included in this page (Just to make sure: *please* escape that SQL query before sending it to the database ;)).

Comment: `WHERE item_category="+$_GET["category_id"]` that isn't the correct syntax. It's a dot and not a plus sign. This isn't JS/C++

Comment: I mean my code above (the comment) was supposing I already got the data from the DB and have them stored in an array called `category`